# Comprobar expresión regular

Tags: java

He de comprobar que la cadena atributo de la clase existente comience por ATG, termine con TGA y su longitud sea múltiplo de 3. Si es cierto el método devuelvo true, false en caso negativo.
Los caracteres que puede poseer el atributo son: C, T, G o A.
Algunos ejemplos de posibles cadenas que puede recibir el método son:

"ATGCGATACTGA" -> sería correcta

"TGACGATACATG" -> incorrecta

"ATGTGA"-> correcta

```
public boolean isProtein(){
        String regex= "^ATG+[ACGT]*TGA$|ATGTGA";
        return bases.matches(regex) && bases.length() % 3 == 0;

    }
```

Comment: ya inetentaste con `^ATG+[ACGT]*TGA$`?

Comment: Sí. El código parece ser correcto pero dentro de la clase en la que está definido, y su correspondiente test no lo pasa. No encuentro el porqué.

Comment: ya intentaste convirtiendo a doble los valores??

Comment: solucionado, el código era correcto

Answer (score 0):

1. `^ATG` que comience por ATG
2. `(?:[ACTG]{3})*` codones en el medio, siempre bases en múltiplos de 3
3. `TGA$` que termine en TGA

Regex:

```
^ATG(?:[ACTG]{3})*TGA$
```

Código:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public boolean isProtein(String bases){
    final String regex = "^ATG(?:[ACTG]{3})*TGA$";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bases);
    
    return matcher.find();
}
```